# Get objects filtered by value of another table

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the following model which links a user to his session:

```
class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

Now I want to get all active sessions from the given user.

How can I do the following SQL in Django 1.10?

```
SELECT * FROM django_session WHERE session_key IN (SELECT session_id FROM usersys_usersession WHERE user_id = 1) AND expire_date > now()
```

Comment: post the models too

Comment: The second table is the standard User model from django

Comment: atleast post the Session table?

Comment: Its The standard session table created from SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want all sessions which are not expired for a given user? Then there would be no reason for a subquery. Just join the user and session table, and compare for the expire_date?

```
UserSession.objects.filter(user_id = 1, session__expire_data__gt = timezone.now())
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.